# Open widgets screen from button

Tags: java, android, widget

I don´t know if it's possible, but I would like to know if it´s possible open widgets screen from a button inside in my app.

thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bring app widget to home screen by code because Android not supported. Only by user action because you can not know does home screen has space to place widget.